# Query with flask-sqlalchmey model class causing db sessions leaking

Tags: python, session, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Pretty frustrated right now.  I have this problem where performing a DB query using the class type (i.e. `User.query.filter(...)` or an instance of the class itself (i.e. `u = User(...)`; `return u.query.filter(...).first()`) results in a new session being created every time.

Eventually when I attempt to perform an add/commit, I get the proverbial:

```
InvalidRequestError: Object '<Loadable at 0x1b02f90>' is already attached to session '1' (this is '4')
```

For what it's worth, I've found that the new sessions continue to get created as a result of:

```
app/_ _ init _ _.py:

@login_manager.user_loader

def load_user(id):

from app.users.models import User
return User.query.get(int(id))
```

All page requests invoke `load_user()` and every time it's hit, I have a new session.  I can say this with confidence because I set breakpoints in
 `/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py`
for both the creation and destruction of sessions. I'm hoping it's something small that will point out my egregious misunderstanding of how these things are allocated. I started out the day with a full head of hair, but I've been scratching my head over this one so long now that I'm going bald.  Please save my hair.

So, taking Miguel's advice and setting a breakpoint at the place of session creation in
`lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py(137)__init__()`
I was able to see that it's a result of a function that I wrote that loads all modules that it sees in a given directory, one by one. Stack trace below:

```
  /home/robert/snak2/run.py(1)<module>()
-> from app import app
  /home/robert/snak2/app/__init__.py(39)<module>()
-> load_all_modules_from_dir('app')
  /home/robert/snak2/app/utils.py(87)load_all_modules_from_dir()
-> ).load_module(full_package_name)
  /usr/lib64/python2.7/pkgutil.py(246)load_module()
-> mod = imp.load_module(fullname, self.file, self.filename, self.etc)
  /home/robert/snak2/app/account/__init__.py(17)<module>()
-> mod.mod_register(MODNAME, MODCAT, NAME, LINK, AUTHOR, DESC, ICON, NAVS)
  /home/robert/snak2/app/loader.py(159)mod_register()
**-> mod = Loadable.query.filter(Loadable.modname == modname).first()(**)**
  /home/robert/snak2/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py(429)__get__()
-> return type.query_class(mapper, session=self.sa.session())
  /home/robert/snak2/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py(70)__call__()
-> return self.registry()
  /home/robert/snak2/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py(864)__call__()
-> return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
> /home/robert/snak2/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py(137)__init__()
-> self.app = db.get_app()
```

Based on information that Miguel has given in his kick a$$ tutorial, I believe it's the line in the stack denoted with the (**) that is actually causing a new session to be created (and persist). But how to make it go away?

Comment: Each request gets a new database session, this is normal and expected.  The problem that you have is not that you are leaking sessions, what happens is that the first session ever created (the one with number 1) has objects attached and was not released. Are you using Flask-WhooshAlchemy by any chance? There is a bug in that extension that causes this error.

Comment: Hey Miguel, thanks for getting back to me.  If you're the same guy that has posted the flask mega tutorial, let me first say that you are a rock star. Those have been quite informative.  Having said that, I think I know what you're getting at here -- I saw the walk through on finding that bug.  Unfortunately, I'm not using Flask-WhooshAlchemy. The reason I used the word "leak" is here is because I don't know how to go back and regain access to those sessions.  If I did, I'd just close them myself. :-/

Comment: Yup, I'm that guy. I believe it's not "sessions", it's just one session that got stuck for some reason. You can obtain more information using a debugger. Put a breakpoint in the session constructor and then start the app. When it breaks you will have a stack trace that will tell you who is creating that session 1 that never goes away. Hopefully that'll give you some more clues.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your valuable time!  Taking your advice and setting breakpoints at the places of session construction, I can see that it's coming from a function that I wrote which registers all modules that it sees in a given directory. I'll update the post.

Comment: You didn't provide enough code as a minimal visible program. So unable to diagnose it. A usual situation is, the `db` be used to create Model and `db.init_app()` is not the same. Hope this clue could be helpful.